# How to extract the following xaml for Image.Triggers to a Style in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got an Image and defined a "ButtonImageStyle" for it.
This makes the button fade in when the mouse hover over it.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
    <Style.Triggers>                    
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also want the button to shrink a little when the mouse is down, so I solved that
using EventTriggers in the Image.Triggers collection. This works, but I can't figure
out how to extract that into the style above so that I don't have to repeat it for every Image.

When I try using the EventTriggers in Style.Triggers it simply tells me that
TargetName cannot be used there, and I don't know what the alternative is.

```
<Image DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
       Source="appbar.page.search.png"
       Width="48"
       Height="48"
       Margin="2,0"
       Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScale"
                    ScaleX="1"
                    ScaleY="1"
                    CenterX="24"
                    CenterY="24" />
  </Image.RenderTransform>
  <Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                           To="0.8"
                           Duration="0:0:0.15"
                           AutoReverse="False" />
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                           To="0.8"
                           Duration="0:0:0.15"
                           AutoReverse="False" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                           To="1.0"
                           Duration="0:0:0.15"
                           AutoReverse="False" />
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                           To="1.0"
                           Duration="0:0:0.15"
                           AutoReverse="False" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

**Update:** I figured I might be going about this the wrong way and
that I should use a ControlTemplate for a Button instead:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
    <Style.Triggers>                    
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Image Source="appbar.page.search.png" 
                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                Stretch="Fill"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}">
            <Image.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="0.8"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                        AutoReverse="False"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                        To="0.8"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                        AutoReverse="False"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="GrowStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="1.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                        AutoReverse="False"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                        To="1.0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                        AutoReverse="False"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Image.Resources>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="1" CenterY="1"/>                         
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkStoryboard}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowStoryboard}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The problem with this version is that the Image will scale down when it is pressed,
but it does not return to its original size when the mouse button is released.
I've tried using "MouseUp" and "MouseLeftButtonUp"

**Update 2**: Just in case someobody wants to use this,
Based on the solution by dbaseman, I've removed the event triggers and replaced it with

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">                            
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkStoryboard}"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowStoryboard}"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual state system is best suited to this.  The Button control comes with a built-in `Pressed` state that you can conveniently target.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
  <Image>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
          <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.15">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                             To="0.5"
                             Duration="0:0:0.15" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                             To="0.5"
                             Duration="0:0:0.15" />
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
          <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.15">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:0.15" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                             To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:0.15" />
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"
                      ScaleY="1"
                      x:Name="scale" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Ok that's a lot cleaner than the EventTriggers, however once the image has been scaled down, it does not scale up. Do I need to provide something for the "default" state and how?

Comment: If I add a VisualState x:Name="Normal" it does 'grow' back if the mouse leaves the button, but no when it's released

Comment: @TimothyP Add the `MouseOver` state in place of `Normal` -- that seems to make it snap back (updated above also).  FYI, this is a great reference for customizing the control template:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx